# C++ how does this work? (array as parameter)

Tags: c++, arrays, parameters

So looking in IDA i found a function like this

```
struct exampleStruct {
    int a, b, c;
};

void example(exampleStruct *(*exampleList)[3])
{
    //blah blah
}
```

so this is the part that confuses me `*(*exampleList)[3])`
from just looking at it i would image i would call the function like this

```
exampleStruct forCall[3];
example(&forCall);
```

then after it is called i would imagine i can fetch the values like so

```
//forCall[0].a
//forCall[2].c
//etc...
```

So my question is, is what i said above correct? e.g. is that how i would call a function like that?

Comment: I am not sure but try it.

Comment: `exampleStruct *(*exampleList)[3]` it is a pointer on array of 3 pointers of struct `exampleStruct`. Probably you should remove outter asterisk to make this code consistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass an array of exampleStruct to example, then the latter would like this:

```
void examplefoo(examplestruct somename[]) {
    allnames[0].a += 1;
}
```

or:

```
void examplefoo(examplestruct* somename) {
    allnames[0].a += 1;
}
```

Basically both are the same: you give the function a pointer to the first element of you array.

This function will take the first element of the array and increase its .a by 1. Let's see how we can call this function.

First you have to create and array of examplestruct, eg.:

```
examplestruct somename;
somename.a = 1;
somename.b = 2;
somename.c = 3;
examplestruct othername;
othername.a = 7;
othername.b = 8;
othername.b = 9;
examplestruct allnames[2] = {somename, othername};
```

And call the function like this:

```
examplefoo(allnames);
```

If you then print allnames[0].a you will see that its value is now 2.